# Constraint on method depends on instances in scope?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

Consider this code:

```
{-# language FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Y where

class C m where

    x :: m

instance {-# overlappable #-} Monoid m => C m where

    x = mempty

instance C Int where

    x = 53
```

What is the type of `x`?

```
λ :type x
x :: C m => m
```

So far — so good. Now remove the `Int` instance. What is the type of `x`?

```
λ :type x
x :: Monoid m => m
```

Surprise!

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in the following blog post:

- [Opaque constraint synonyms](https://kcsongor.github.io/opaque-constraint-synonyms/)

In short: GHC is smart enough to see that you have only one instance of the `C` typeclass and decided that it's the only possible instance, so every time it sees `C m` constraint, it replaces it with `Monoid m` because they are equivalent.

**N.B.**   As @chi further explains in a comment:

When GHC finds a constraint `C t`, it tries to solve it. If if finds a matching `instance (...) => C t where ...`, the constraint is replaced with the context `(...)`. This is repeated as much as possible. The final constraint appears in the type (or triggers a "unsolved" type error). This process is justified since there can only be at most one matching instance. Overlapping instances change this, and prevent this context reduction when multiple instances (in scope!) match, roughly. It is a *fragile* extension, to be used with some care.

Comment: I see, so this is a known... _feature?.._ However, this post does not explain the nature of it. Is it a side effect of type inference? Or is it intentional?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov not sure whether it's a _feature_ or just an implementation detail. But I'm not the blog post author. So probably you have better chances understanding this behaviour by asking GHC developers directly.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov When GHC finds a constraint `C t`, it tries to solve it. If if finds a matching `instance (...) => C t where ...`, the constraint is replaced with the context `(...)`. This is repeated as much as possible. The final constraint appears in the type (or triggers a "unsolved" type error). This process is justified since there can only be at most one matching instance. Overlapping instances change this, and prevent this context reduction when multiple instances (in scope!) match, roughly. It is a _fragile_ extension, to be used with some care.

Comment: Perhaps this last comment of @chi could be integrated into the answer?

Comment: @chi I took the liberty to integrate your comment. I feel I can accept the answer this way.